# Projectiles firing from wrong players

Tags: c#, networking, xna

I'm working on a small game for my friends. So far i've gotten the Networking right, both players can fly around and it's all in sync.

Now I've added projectiles (lasers) which I spawn like this:

```
if (_mou.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed 
         && oldState.LeftButton 
         != ButtonState.Released)               
         {
             if (timeSinceShot > timePerShot)
            {
                timeSinceShot = 0;
                bulletRotation = rotation; //Rotation of the players ship
                laser.addLaser(myID, bulletRotation, localPosition);
            }
         }
```

This works fine, it fires the laser from my ship, but doesn't get displayed yet.

Now when I fire I call this:

```
om.Write(bulletRotation); //Sends the rotation to the server
```

And when the server has received it, it sends it back to all players, including the one who shot.

Here's how I receive the data on the client and write it to the lasers list:

```
if (who != myID)
{
   try
   {
      float laserR = msg.ReadFloat();
      laser.addLaser(who, laserR, player.players[i].position);
   }
   catch { }
}
```

Now when I test it on 2 clients and fire, I can see myself firing at the 2nd client which is good. However it not only fires on the 2nd client but also on my client's 2nd player.

Edit: who is a RemoteUniqueIdentifier and myID is the clients RemoteUniqueIdentifier

Here's a picture of my problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYJyW.png
(can't upload it yet as I don't have 10 rep.)

EDIT 2:

This is how the server send it's data to all the players:

```
foreach (NetConnection player in server.Connections)
                    {
                        // ... send information about every other player (actually including self)
                        foreach (NetConnection otherPlayer in server.Connections)
                        {
                            // send position update about 'otherPlayer' to 'player'
                            NetOutgoingMessage om = server.CreateMessage();

                            // write who this position is for
                            om.Write(player.RemoteUniqueIdentifier);
                            om.Write(otherPlayer.RemoteUniqueIdentifier);

                            if (otherPlayer.Tag == null)
                                otherPlayer.Tag = new float[4];

                            float[] pos = otherPlayer.Tag as float[];

                            om.Write(pos[0]); // velocity X
                            om.Write(pos[1]); // velocity X
                            om.Write(pos[2]); // rotation

                            if (!noLasers)
                            {
                                om.Write(pos[3]); // bullet rotation
                            }

                            // send message
                            server.SendMessage(om, player, NetDeliveryMethod.Unreliable);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: what is `i` in `players[i]`???

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < player.players.Count; i++)

Comment: OK, and when you debug and set breakpoint to place behind IF, how many times is it executed?

Comment: Depends on how many players are online, so 2 players would cause it to run twice.

Comment: OK, so if code behind `if (who != myID)` is executed twice, that's the reason that you have two lasers.  BTW, I like your game :)

Comment: Thank you :), and the who != myID only compares if the who key [the one who sends the data] is not equal to the clients unique id. I guess that I have to change the way the Server sends the data to prevent is problem.

Comment: :) have I earned upvote and acceptance of the answer? :)

Comment: oh, totally forgot that. Accepted answer for you kind sir. (cant upvote yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `RemoteUniqueIdentifier` is an object of some class, and you are trying to naively pass it through the wire, you will never be able to test local version and one you got from the server for equality.

Reconstructed object on the 'other side' will always have a reference that can't be compared with the original.

In that case, you might have an option to switch from `RemoteUniqueIdentifier` to some immutable type such as `int` or `Guid`, even `string` will work.

Comment: RemoteUniqueIdentifier is the same on the Server as on the Client.

Comment: Please tell me what it is?  Is that a class of some sort?

Comment: I'm using Lidgren Networking library. The RemoteUniqueIdentifier is a random generated key that is used as long as you're connected to the server, when you reconnect it's re-generated.

Comment: NetIncomingMessage msg;
msg.SenderConnection.RemoteUniqueIdentifier

Comment: I downloaded complete library to find that RemoteUniqueIdentifier is of type long.  Anyway, when you debug, do you enter into the code behind if twice?